# Uncaught Error: Class not found - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to run a script within my laravel project when I am having difficulty with the model class not found error.

My model class is located at :

App\UserLoginAudit;

I am calling my class like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Scripts;

use App\UserLoginAudit as user_login_audit;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserSignOut {
private $currentDate;
private $report;
public function __construct() {
    $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $this->doQuery();
}

private function doQuery () {
    $this->report = new user_login_audit();

    //die(print_r($this->report,true));

    $this->report->select(
        DB::raw('TIMEDIFF(NOW(),user_login_audit.last_accessed) as time_difference'),
        'user.user_id',
        'user_login_audit.ip_address'
    )
    ->join(
        'tutor_times.user',
        'user.user_id',
        '=',
        'user_login_audit.user_id'
    )
    ->whereNull('user_login_audit.time_out_type')
    ->where('last_accessed','<=',$this->currentDate)
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

    die(print_r($this->report,true));

    $this->processQuery();
}

private function processQuery () {
    foreach ($this->report as $record) {
        if ($record['time_difference'] > 5) {
            $lookup = user_login_audit
                ::where('user_id','=',$record['user_id'])
                ->where('ip_address','=',$record['ip_address'])
                ->whereNull('time_out_type')
                ->first();

            if (!empty($lookup)) {
                $lookup->time_out_type = "system";
                $lookup->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
$obj = new UserSignOut();
```

Have I missed something out ? please can someone help me with this issue

When I run the script this is the error I get:

Uncaught Error: Class 'App\UserLoginAudit' not found in /home/public/TutorTimes/app/Scripts/user_sign_out.php:17

Comment: How do you run the script? If you run it directly, the autoloader won't be registered and PHP won't be able to find the class

Comment: Sudo php php file name

Comment: So the autoloading won't work, take a loot at my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the name of your file and class, I can understand that you run/load your script manually.
In this case, you won't load the composer's autoloader which should load the classes for you.

Try to create a custom artisan command and run it with `php artisan {commandName}`.

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands) for the creation of the custom artisan command.

**** Update ****

For your need, use this command (and don't forget to register it):

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\UserLoginAudit as user_login_audit;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UserSignOut extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'user-sign-our';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = '...';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->report = new user_login_audit();

        $this->report->select(
            DB::raw('TIMEDIFF(NOW(),user_login_audit.last_accessed) as time_difference'),
            'user.user_id',
            'user_login_audit.ip_address'
        )
            ->join(
                'tutor_times.user',
                'user.user_id',
                '=',
                'user_login_audit.user_id'
            )
            ->whereNull('user_login_audit.time_out_type')
            ->where('last_accessed', '<=', $this->currentDate)
            ->get()
            ->toArray();

        die(print_r($this->report, true));

        $this->processQuery();
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    private function processQuery()
    {
        foreach ($this->report as $record) {
            if ($record['time_difference'] > 5) {
                $lookup = user_login_audit
                    ::where('user_id', '=', $record['user_id'])
                    ->where('ip_address', '=', $record['ip_address'])
                    ->whereNull('time_out_type')
                    ->first();

                if ( ! empty($lookup)) {
                    $lookup->time_out_type = "system";
                    $lookup->save();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To run it, use:

```
php artisan user-sign-our
```

Comment: require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

Comment: Would this make any difference ? Since I am not too sure how to go about using the custom artisan command ?

Comment: That's the right way to write custom scripts in Laravel. You can add the require line as @jomin_george94 said, but you will probably face more related bugs in the future

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to go about creating customer artisan command and how to use that to here ?? I know how to create the custome artisan command however does that mean I am using that class to do the script ??

Comment: I changed you script to be artisan command, see the update above

Comment: Thank you, however I am getting this error now: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Console\Command' not found

Comment: where did you put the script? how did you run it?

Comment: So like you said I made  a artisan command first by running : php artisan make:command userSignOut
And then changed it so that it matches up with your answer above and then ran the script and I get this error

Comment: Did you run your script with `php artisan user-sign-our`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you meant  by that ?

Comment: You need to run your script from the console with the command I wrote, and not with `php app\Console\Command\userSignOut.php`

Comment: That worked, just one more question, if I were to use crontab how would I run this script ? with the artisan command ?

Comment: You can run the artisan command, or use Laravel scheduling and define when the code will run in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that won't work. To use Laravel classes, you need Laravel's autoloader.

The correct way of doing this is a [custom Artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#writing-commands).

Comment: (And you shouldn't use `sudo` unless you **need** to. This script shouldn't require it at all.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 use \App\UserLoginAudit as user_login_audit;
```

Comment: @jomin_george94 what's the namespace of UserLoginAudi?

Comment: This is it : namespace App;